# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data not available' while returning the value from function

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have created a function to create new column. While returning the value it is giving error

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data not available'

sample df:

```
col1   col2 
abc     10
def     20
ghi     30
```

function:

```
def fun1():
  if (df['col1'].isin(['xyz'])).any():
    output=df.loc[df['col1']=='xyz',['col2']]
    return output
  else:
    output = "data not available"
    return output
```

Calling function like below:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(fun1(),axis=1)
```

When I called function I am getting above error. I have searched about it but could not able to find solution. What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
def fun1(val):
    if (val['col1'] in 'xyz'):
        return val['col2']
    else:
        return "data not available"
```

Finally:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(fun1,axis=1)
```

**Note:**  You can reduce the cost of `apply()` by:

```
df['new_column']=df['col2'].where(df['col1'].eq('xyz'),"data not available")
```

**OR**

```
#import numpy as np
df['new_column']=np.where(df['col1'].eq('xyz'),df['col2'],"data not available")
```

Comment: ```df['new_column']=df['col2'].where(df['col1'].eq('xyz'),"data not available")``` one line answer.It worked. Thank you